# gtklist[c code]: how to get the selection of a GtkList

Tags: c, list, gtk, selection

Followed is the code referring to [very old gtk+1.x FAQ](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/help/gtk+-1.1.3/gtkfaq-4.html). The purpose is to get the selection of a `GtkList`. I know GtkList is deprecated and should be replaced with GtkTreeView + GtkListStore. I do know how to use GtkListStore. However, I do want to use GtkList in current situation since GtkListStore is more complex.

The `problem` for the code below is that it doesn't print anything no matter how many items I select. Please help. My gtk+ version is 2.10.11.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void list_changed (GtkList *list, GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
  GList   *items;

  items=GTK_LIST(list)->selection;
  printf("Selected Items: ");
  while (items) 
  {
    if (GTK_IS_LIST_ITEM(items->data))
        printf("%d ", (guint) 
    gtk_object_get_user_data(items->data));
    items=items->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    GtkWidget *window, *list_item, *list;
    guint i;
    gchar *list_items[]={"Item0", "Item1", "foo", "last Item",};
    guint nlist_items=sizeof(list_items)/sizeof(list_items[0]);

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), window);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GtkList");
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    list=gtk_list_new();
    gtk_list_set_selection_mode(GTK_LIST(list), GTK_SELECTION_MULTIPLE);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), list);
    gtk_widget_show (list);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(list), "select-child", G_CALLBACK(list_changed), window);

    for (i = 0; i < nlist_items; i++)
    {
      list_item=gtk_list_item_new_with_label(list_items[i]);
      gtk_object_set_user_data(GTK_OBJECT(list_item), (gpointer)i);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(list), list_item);
      gtk_widget_show(list_item);
    }

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GtkList is so deprecated it's not even funny. you should *never* use it in newly written code.

Comment: also, gtk+ 2.10 is, at this point, more than 8 years old. you won't ever get any bug fixed, or support, by using that kind of release.

Answer (score 3):

instead of using a long since deprecated widget like `GtkList`, maybe you should detail which problems you have with `GtkTreeView` and `GtkListStore`. for instance, creating the tree view and populating it with labels can be achieved using this code (I broke it down for ease of comprehension):

```
enum {
  COLUMN_TEXT,

  N_COLUMNS
};

static const char *labels[] = {
  "Item 0",
  "Item 1",
  "foo",
  "Last item"
};

GtkTreeModel *
populate_store (void);
{
  GtkListStore *store;
  int i;

  store = gtk_list_store_new (N_COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING);

  for (i = 0; i < G_N_ELEMENTS (labels); i++)
    {
      gtk_list_store_insert_with_values (store, NULL, i,
                                         COLUMN_TEXT, labels[i],
                                         -1);
    }

  return GTK_TREE_MODEL (store);
}

GtkWidget *
create_tree_view (GtkTreeModel *model)
{
  GtkWidget *widget;

  /* renderer for the column */
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();

  /* column, to pack renderers and bind them to a column in the model */
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Items",
                                                     renderer,
                                                     "text", COLUMN_TEXT,
                                                     NULL);

  /* text view, to pack all columns */
  widget = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model (model);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column (GTK_TREE_VIEW (widget), column);

  return widget;
}
```

if you have access to later versions of GTK+, you'd also have better convenience API, but the code above is written using the API as it was available in GTK+ 2.10.

there's a pretty comprehensive tutorial available online at: http://scentric.net/tutorial

if you had access to GTK+ 3.10 you'd also be able to use GtkListBox, which is a simpler widget that allows you to pack multiple widgets in a list; it does not allow multiple selection, and does not scale to multiple thousand items, but for simpler use cases it's probably more appropriate.

my heartfelt suggestion is to

- start using `GtkTreeView`
- update, if at all possible, to a recent version of GTK+

  - and if you could update to GTK+ 3.x it would definitely be better.

Comment: I don' have any problems to use GtkListStore since I have already used it more in my code. For the issue in question, it is a simple case that shows only one column and provides multiple selections. As your code shows, to use GtkListStore, we use renderer to define column type and retrieve iter to get row. For my issue, I just wanted to use GtkList to simplify code. But Gtklist seemed not to support multiple selection well, I have to surrender and use GtkListStore instead. Anyway, thank you for your post.

Comment: I am using MinGW to develop codes. I have ever tried GTK+ 3.x(not official release) once but some functions in `demo` quit abnormally. Then I gave up trying to find what problem is. I maintain my code in two version: 2.10.11 and 2.22.1. I just looked through gtk web site and surprisly found it released 3.6.4 for win32. The official web site have always released 2.24.x as the latest version for a long time. Maybe I should give a try for the latest official 3.x release.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
items=GTK_LIST(list)->selection;
```

`GtkList` is an opaque struct and you are not supposed to access it: the internal fields are to be considered implementation details and, as you have just discovered, could be bogus data.

From the [API doc](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkList.html), it seems there is no way to get the current selection so you must handle it by yourself. The following is an example implementation that also stores the order in which the selection has been performed:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
dump_items(const GSList *items)
{
    const GSList *item;
    gint n;

    g_print("Selection:");
    for (item = items; item; item = item->next) {
        n = GPOINTER_TO_INT(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(item->data), "n"));
        g_print(" %d", n);
    }
    g_print("\n");
}

static void
add_item(GtkList *list, GtkWidget *item, GSList **p_items)
{
    *p_items = g_slist_remove(*p_items, item);
    *p_items = g_slist_append(*p_items, item);
    dump_items(*p_items);
}

static void
remove_item(GtkList *list, GtkWidget *item, GSList **p_items)
{
    *p_items = g_slist_remove(*p_items, item);
    dump_items(*p_items);
}

gint
main(gint argc, gchar *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *item, *list;
    GSList *items = NULL;
    gchar **p_label, *labels[] = {
        "Item0", "Item1", "foo", "last Item",
        NULL
    };

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GtkList");

    list = gtk_list_new();
    gtk_list_set_selection_mode(GTK_LIST(list), GTK_SELECTION_MULTIPLE);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), list);
    g_signal_connect(list, "select-child", G_CALLBACK(add_item), &items);
    g_signal_connect(list, "unselect-child", G_CALLBACK(remove_item), &items);

    for (p_label = labels; *p_label; ++p_label) {
      item = gtk_list_item_new_with_label(*p_label);
      g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(item), "n", GINT_TO_POINTER(p_label - labels));
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(list), item);
    }

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To ntd: in GTK_SELECTION_MULTIPLE mode, how to unselect a item? Hold `CTRL` with left mouse button clicking can toggle the selection but never emit the signal `unselect-child`. In this case, the selection is messing.

Comment: To ntd: for GTK_SELECTION_SINGLE mode, my original code works.

Comment: @warem: *Implementation details* basically means everything can happen. Furthermore, *deprecated* means no errors will be fixed, so if `GTK_SELECTION_SINGLE` is not working because of a bug you will be on your own. Here I'm ansering to your question but I'd double ebassi suggestion: just update your code if you want to make your (and your users) life saner.